# Twisted not logging all python output

Tags: python, twisted

I wish to capture all the output that is visible to me when I'm not using Twisted.

This includes all logging and print statements, from both my code and any third-party libraries I use.

I am unable to modify third-party libraries to employ Twisted's logging, for instance.

My goal is to redirect all the output so that it can be seen on my server terminal and in the logs.

Comment: What did you try